# Is there any way to vectorize the matlab code or another approach to reduce its running time?

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry

Is there anyway to improve the below codes? It takes much time in higher values. I'd be appreciated if a solution for improving be advised.

```
term3=0;
ngrain=70;
etas = rand(512*512,70);
glist = round(1,70);
en = zeros(1,70);
for i=1:70
 en(i)=0.493;
end
for igrain=1:ngrain
for jgr=1:ngrain+nrex
    if(glist(jgr)== 1)
        den(igrain,jgr)=en(jgr)-en(igrain);
        term3=term3-8/pi*(etas(:,igrain).*etas(:,jgr)).^0.5*den(igrain,jgr);
    end
end
end
```

Comment: A way to improve the question might be to describe what your code does. Also can you give some sample data, define all your variables and functions, maybe mention the shapes of the vectors etc.

Comment: If you can provide more information or give dummy data for your example, then it would be easier to get more help....

Comment: the nrex equals zero. and other requirement for solving the code is mentioned.

Comment: and glist is round(rand(1,70))

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. It will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: We don't do code reviews here. However, [codereview.SE] does.

Comment: Since `en` is a constant, `en-en` end up to be equal to `0` and `term3` will always be `0`. So the whole code can be sum up with `term3 = 0;`. If this is not the expected answer then you will have to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please be more precise in the future. Here are a couple of hints to improve your coding:

Building a vector out of constants can be achieved in several ways (unfortunately, you picked the least efficient one):

- a for-loop (with or without pre-allocation of memory, you did allocate, so that is good!)
- use **1** * constant => `ones(1,70)*0.493`
- repeat the 1x1 matrix: repmat() => `repmat(1,70,0.493)` (this is the most efficient approach, you may check this using `tic()` and `toc()` )

Anyway, this wasn't your bottleneck.
You can do logical comparisons directly instead of looping and using if:

```
lg = glist == 1;
idx = find(lg);
for i = 1:length(idx)
   jgr = idx(i)
end
```

Note that your example does not work because `nrex` is not defined. It would also be great if you format your code nicer (consistent spacing, indention, a naming that is a bit more intuitive)